# Changing the indexing order of BitArray in Python

Tags: python, bitstring

I am using a `BitArray` in my python script, and I was wondering if there is a way to change the indexes order of the `BitArray` that I create. Right now the indexes are from 0 to N-1 where N is the number of bits.  Is there away to change the indexes to go from N-1 to O?

```
dataBits = BitArray('0b10100000')
print(dataBits[0])
```

This above two lines return the first bit `True` because the order of indexes is from 0 to N-1. Can I change the order of indexes for this to return the last bit `False`?

Comment: What is returning anything `True` or `False`?

Comment: It may be effective to subclass the BitArray class and add a custom method that allows you to achieve that

Comment: Is it acceptable to reverse the bits before you create your `BitArray`? IE: `dataBits = BitArray('10100000'[::-1])`? Otherwise, you should subclass and implement your own `__getitem__` and `__iter__` methods. The first is preferable since there might be other methods in `BitArray` that depend on the order and might lead to "unexpected" behavior. Also, where is the documentation for the `BitArray` library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you're looking for is the module variable `lsb0`:

```
bitstring.lsb0 = True
dataBits = bitstring.BitArray('0b10100000')
print(dataBits[0])
```

Prints out `False`.